# Can two NSManagedObjectContext on two different threads save (persist to disk) at same time?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Objective C gurus, I have a quick question to ask:

I now have two different threads running in the background, each with an `NSManagedObjectContext` assigned.

Now, the question is : is it safe for the two `NSManagedObjectContext` save [persist to disk] using a common / shared `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` at the same time?

In other words, can two different background threads persist to disk simultanously?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is not thread safe but you haven't to worry about it. A `NSManagedObjectContext` knows how to lock the store when uses it (during a save).

So, it's right to have multiple contexts that share the same store. This is the recommended approach from [App Store Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html):

> Create a separate managed object context for each thread and share a
>   single persistent store coordinator.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, so it's safe to assume that it's OK for two `NSManagedObjectContext` to save simultaneously, right?

Comment: if a context is saving, the second waits for the first to finish. so they happen in two different times.